# Searching an object in ArrayList

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, binary-search

I am storing objects in ArrayList, where my pojo is as

```
public class POJOSortableContacts {
    private Long id;
    private String displayName;


    public POJOSortableContacts(Long id, String displayName) {

        super();
        this.id           = id;
        this.displayName  = displayName;
    }

    //Setter and Getters
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    //This will be used to sectioned header.
    public String getLabel() {
        return Character.toString(displayName.charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
    }



    //Sortable categories
    //Sort by Contact name
    public static Comparator<POJOSortableContacts> COMPARE_BY_NAME = new Comparator<POJOSortableContacts>() {
        public int compare(POJOSortableContacts one, POJOSortableContacts other) {
            return one.getDisplayName().compareToIgnoreCase(other.getDisplayName());
            //return s1.toLowerCase().compareTo(s2.toLowerCase()); //it returns lower_case word first and then upper_case
        }
    };

    //Sort by id
    public static Comparator<POJOSortableContacts> COMPARE_BY_ID = new Comparator<POJOSortableContacts>() {
        public int compare(POJOSortableContacts one, POJOSortableContacts other) {
            return one.id.compareTo(other.id);
        }
    };
}
```

and Arraylist structure is as

```
ArrayList<POJOSortableContacts> contactArrayList = new ArrayList<POJOSortableContacts>()
```

, I want to search an object from contactArrayList by id (for example I want an object which id is 20), I want to use binarysearch for this. So how can it will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
POJOSortableContacts contact = Collections.binarySearch(contactArrayList,
                                               new POJOSortableContacts(20, ""),
                                               COMPARE_BY_ID);
```

The new `POJOSortableContacts` is just a dummy object to act as the key.

Of course, this will only work if your list is sorted by ID to start with - you can't use a binary search on an unsorted list (or on a list which is sorted in a different way).

Comment: I am using Collections.sort(contactArrayList, POJOSortableContacts.COMPARE_BY_ID); to sort my collection. then how can I get that object/ value?

Comment: @pankaj: You use the result of Collections.binarySearch. I've edited my answer to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 1):

I will rather suggest that you use a HashMap.

```
Map<Long,POJOSortableContacts> contactMap = new HashMap<Long,POJOSortableContacts>();
```

Fill up your contactMap like this:

```
contactMap.put(myContact.getId(), myContact);
```

Searching then becomes trivial:

```
POJOSortableContacts myContact = contactMap.get(myID);
```

Comment: Yes this will be good. But I must have a sorted list of objects by name. thats why I am using ArrayList.

Comment: If that is the case you will have to (re)sort your `ArrayList` before you will be able to do a binary search.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use binary search, your collection must be sorted. You *could* sort your `ArrayList` each time before your search, but that would negate the advantage of using binary search (you could just do a linear search over the unsorted list and still be faster).

Comment: If I have more than 5000 objects then what should I prefer? I am confused. I was preferring binary search because of it is faster than linear search.

Comment: @pankaj: **if** your list is always sorted, then binary search is clearly the better solution. But if you have to sort before each search, then you might be slowing yourself down artificially. But it depends a lot on your code and circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList has a method  - BinarySearch, which takes object to search as a parameter.

```
POJOSortableContacts contactToSearch = new POJOSortableContacts(someId, "Name");
POJOSortableContacts myContact = contactArrayList.BinarySearch(contactToSearch);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sidestepping the question a bit, if you can't have duplicates in the list you'd likely be better served by using a `SortedSet` to store the contacts. No sorting before using `binarySearch` anymore...